# Settings API - easiest way of validating checkboxes?

Tags: admin, options, settings-api

I'm using Settings API and I can't get checkboxes to work, if they're set to "false" they're not even being $_POST and that's the point.

[Stephen Harris &  Chip Bennett explained it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41865/1869), but I believe their way is not simple enough (especially for me, not PHP-guy at all). Do I REALLY need a few custom PHP functions and custom-named submit buttons for every form just to get this simple thing working?

My settings look much like:

```
register_setting('XX_theme_settings', 'XX_theme_settings', 'setting_validate' );

add_settings_section('theme_options', 'Theme Options', 'theme_options_generate', 'page1' ); 
add_settings_field( 'XX_Option1', 'Option 1', 'checkbox', 'page1', 'theme_options', 'XX_Option1', $args = array('id' => 'checkbox1', 'type' => 'checkbox') );
add_settings_field( 'XX_Option2', 'Option 2', 'checkbox', 'page1', 'theme_options', 'XX_Option2', $args = array('id' => 'checkbox2', 'type' => 'checkbox') );
```

Then I generate checkboxes with this callback function:

```
function checkbox($args) {
    $options = get_option('XX_theme_settings');
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'. $args['id'] .'" value="true"'; if($options[$args['id']]==true) { echo 'checked="checked'; }; echo '/>';
    echo $args['type'];  
}
```

Now, everything I need is a good validate callback:

```
function setting_validate($input) {
   // Firstly it should find all fields of type == "checkbox" 
   // (I'm not sure why should I check which field was just being sent, 
   // is updating all the checkboxes from different sections a big no-no?
   // it is much easier indeed.
   // Now set the ones missing to false/0 and the rest to true/1.
   // Then merge everything like below:

   $options = get_option('XX_theme_settings');
   $merged = array_merge($options, $input);  
   return $merged;  
}
```

So the question is: **how to list all Settings Api checkboxes and then set the right ones to true?**

I guess it'd look something like that:

```
$options = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'checkbox1',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'page' => 'page1',
         ),
        array(
            'id' => 'checkbox2',
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'page' => 'page1',
         ),
);

function setting_validate($input) {
   foreach($options as $option) {
     if($option['type'] == "checkbox") { 
        //set it to 1 if sent
     }
   }

   $options = get_option('XX_theme_settings');
   $merged = array_merge($options, $input);  
   return $merged;  
}
```

Thanks :)

[Here's how Chip Bennett does it exactly](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/options-register.php#L70), but even with all these great comments I can't get how it exactly works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the setting in question is `$setting`, and is a checkbox type, you validate it like so:

```
<?php
$valid_input[$setting] = ( isset( $input[$setting] ) && true == $input[$setting] ? true : false );
?>
```

In this case, `$input` is the *form data passed to the validation callback*, where `$input` is an array-of-arrays. The validation method is known as *whitelisting*, where the *current settings array* is called (in this case, as `$valid_input`), and each setting in the settings array is only updated if the value in `$input[$setting]` passes the validation.

With checkboxes, if the checkbox isn't *set*, then the setting itself doesn't get populated in the `$input` array. So, the first step to validate it is to **determine if it's been set in `$input`**. The second step is to ensure that the value that is set is `true` (or `'true'`, or `'on'`, or whatever it is to which you set the checkbox value in the settings form). If both those conditions are met, return `true`; otherwise, return `false`.

See: it's quite simple, really. :)

#### Edit

Regarding this:

```
function setting_validate($input) {
   foreach($options as $option) {
     if($option['type'] == "checkbox") { 
        //set it to 1 if sent
     }
   }

   $options = get_option('XX_theme_settings');
   $merged = array_merge($options, $input);  
   return $merged;  
}
```

...that's not *exactly* the way you want to do it. You want to limit the return value to *valid* options; that is, you want to return, explicitly, the settings that you know you've defined. If, somehow, someone can populate `$input` with additional data - i.e. malicious code - your method would simply pass that additional data *right into the database*.

Don't do an `array_merge()`. Update each `$valid_options[$setting]` separately/individually, and only ever return `$valid_options`.

Here's the process:

1. Define the *currently valid* data:

   ```
   $valid_input = get_option( 'XX_theme_settings' );
   ```
2. Update the *currently valid* data with `$input` *only if* `$input` passes your validation/sanitization.
3. Then return the *updated, currently valid* data.

If the fields are being *generated* dynamically, then you should also *step through them* dynamically, in your validation callback. You have this correct, with `foreach( $options as $option )`.

Putting it all together might look like this:

```
<?php
function setting_validate( $input ) {
    // Get current setting values
    $valid_options = get_option( 'XX_theme_options' );
    // Get option parameters array
    // Note: XX_theme_get_option_parameters() function
    // should be defined to return the array you've 
    // defined for $options
    $options = XX_theme_get_option_parameters();
    // Now step through the option parameters,
    // and validate each $input[$option]
    foreach( $options as $option ) {
         // If $option['type] is a checkbox
         if( 'checkbox' == $option['type'] ) { 
             // verify that $input[$option] is set
             // and is set with a valid value;
             // if so, set $valid_input[$option] to 1
             $valid_input[$option] = ( isset( $input[$option] && true == $input[$option] ? 1 : 0 );
         }
     }
     // Return the updated $valid_input array
     return $valid_input;
}
?>
```

Comment: Chip Bennett, it's all becoming clearer now, I'm a bit scared when it comes to editing validation callbacks (see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43749/broken-settings-api ), so I'll ask before doing - is this code valid: http://pastebin.com/5fmqWkDA ? Of course fields are being generated dynamically based on $options arrays. Thanks a lot, you're really patient ;)

Comment: See updated answer. I've tried to step through your code, rearranging as necessary.

Comment: @ChipBennett You are the Settings API boss for true.

Comment: It still doesn't save checkboxes, XX_theme_get_option_parameters() returns $options array, but nothing happes when I submit data. When I tried adding another if statement, like: "else if ('textarea' == $option['type']) { $valid_input[$option] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input[$option] ); } I'm getting tons of ": Illegal offset type" errors.

Comment: The next thing to look at, then, is your setting callback. What are the contents of `$args` passed to the checkbox field callback?

Comment: @BrianFegter thanks :) but if *anyone* is the Settings API boss, it would be Otto.

Comment: Chip Bennett, I'm passing "type" and "id" as an argument, I know creating separate callbacks for different fields is not elegant, but just modified my code so it's much shorter and easier to share: http://pastebin.com/QrxmTzvm

Comment: Okay, next question: in the rendered markup, does the form-field ID look like `XX_theme_options[$setting]`?

Comment: I was trying both XX_theme_settings[$setting] and [$setting] only. When I was merging (and everything was working fine, excepting checkboxes) I used id="[$setting]" and name="XX_theme_settings[$setting]" and it was perfectly fine. I was getting cofident with this settings api but once again I'm totally confused, especially when I'm checking oenology where you do things that work with this theme, but not with mine. I'm going to try to figure it out today, but I don't even know where to start looking.

Comment: Sorry; I meant `name`, rather than `id`.

Comment: Chip Bennett, no problem, names are perfectly fine, I'm investigating $options arrays now. I'm wondering, is it possible to somehow display/echo results of the validating function? So I could see what's being sent? It will make finding the issue a lot easier.

Comment: Sure. Just call `var_dump( $variable ); die;` inside your `register_settings()` callback function, and you'll see the contents of `$variable` when you click submit on the settings page.